# Javascript Div remote server cross domain populating

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, getelementbyid, populate

i'd like to put in html pages around a javascript that call a remote javascript file in my server, elaborate datas by give content back to the html page where the javascript will populate a div by id with the given data.

what's a possible way to perform it? the data will be calculated in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsonp/info)

Comment: Pinging you on an old post, would you mind elaborating here (so the entire context of your answer is not just a link)?

Comment: Actually, yes. Not only is the link sufficient information, it is on StackOverflow. The only reason it isn't a duplicate answer is because the information is in a wiki page rather then as an answer.